# What languages were used to build Wordpress?

Tags: php

Which programming languages were used to create WordPress?

Comment: What are the [actual problems that you face](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress is based on PHP. The dynamic data is stored in a MySQL-Database. For viewing the front- & backend HTML and JavaScript are used. For special operations like the media-upload there are also used technics like Flash and Silverlight.
As developer of themes or plugins u can use every programming language for web development.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia:

> WordPress is a free and open source blogging tool and a dynamic
>   content management system (CMS) based on **PHP** and **MySQL**.

It's back end also uses **JavaScript** and naturally **CSS**.

Comment: And depending on the theme or plugin(s) you use, you may also find AJAX (JavaScript and XML)